# Extracting a file with JUnrar

Tags: java, compression

I asked a question earlier about extracting RAR archives in Java and someone pointed me to JUnrar. The official site is down but it seems to be quite widely used as I found a lot of discussions about it online.

Could someone show me how to use JUnrar to extract all the files in an archive? I found a little snippet online but it doesn't seem to work. It shows each item in the archive to be a directory even if it is a file.

```
    Archive rar = new Archive(new File("C://Weather_Icons.rar"));
    FileHeader fh = rar.nextFileHeader();

    while(fh != null){
        if (fh.isDirectory()) {
             logger.severe("directory: " + fh.getFileNameString() ); 
        }

        //File out = new File(fh.getFileNameString());
        //FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(out);
        //rar.extractFile(fh, os);
        //os.close();
        fh=rar.nextFileHeader();

    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, the webpage for downloading the JUnrar is not available anymore. Could you please give me another link to download the library of it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://github.com/edmund-wagner/junrar

Comment: now at https://github.com/junrar/junrar/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

May be you should also check [this](https://github.com/junrar/junrar/blob/bb362df3e1e5471e58f6322c91b7b1c9a8ebaef1/src/main/java/com/github/junrar/MVTest.java) snippet code. A copy of which can be found below.

```
public class MVTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filename = "/home/rogiel/fs/home/movies/vp.mp3.part1.rar";
        File f = new File(filename);
        Archive a = null;
        try {
            a = new Archive(new FileVolumeManager(f));
        } catch (RarException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (a != null) {
            a.getMainHeader().print();
            FileHeader fh = a.nextFileHeader();
            while (fh != null) {
                try {
                    File out = new File("/home/rogiel/fs/test/"
                            + fh.getFileNameString().trim());
                    System.out.println(out.getAbsolutePath());
                    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(out);
                    a.extractFile(fh, os);
                    os.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (RarException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                fh = a.nextFileHeader();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been looking for the original source but Googling didn't help. Thanks Ozhan.

Comment: updated snippet [here](https://github.com/junrar/junrar/blob/master/src/test/java/com/github/junrar/MVTest.java)

Comment: Thanks @Miguel, i changed the link with yours its better to use new example

Comment: @cdp4j snipped code link isn't working. Please update

Comment: @cdp4j thanks...I'll try it..nice to see the repo moved to gitlab.